# Unable to call a function twice on the same execution on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to run thie following code. It throws me a ***TypeError: hello is not a function*** on the second call of ***Logger.log(hello());***

Here are the two functions:

```
function hello() {
  return hello = 'hello';
}

function testHello() {
  Logger.log(hello());
  Logger.log(hello());
}
```

Any help explaining why this happens and a workaround to it would be very appreciated.

Comment: You're overwriting the function with a string the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when I saw your script, in your script, the following flow is run.

1. At 1st running `Logger.log(hello());` of `testHello()`, `hello()` is run as a function and `hello` of string value is returned. At that time, `hello` is assigned with a string value. By this, `hello` is changed from function to string as the global.
2. At 2nd running `Logger.log(hello());`, `hello` is string. By this, an error like `TypeError: hello is not a function` occurs.

   - I thought that this is the reason of your issue.

For example, when `typeof hello` is used in your script, you can see the change of type. The sample script is as follows.

```
function hello() {
  return hello = 'hello';
}

function testHello() {
  Logger.log(typeof hello);
  Logger.log(hello());
  Logger.log(typeof hello);
  Logger.log(hello());
}
```

When this script is run, you can see the following values in the log.

```
function
hello
string
TypeError: hello is not a function <--- An error occurs here.
```

If you want to avoid this error, how about the following modification?

```
function hello() {
  var hello = 'hello'; // or let or const instead of var
  return hello;
}

function testHello() {
  Logger.log(typeof hello);
  Logger.log(hello());
  Logger.log(typeof hello);
  Logger.log(hello());
}
```

In this case, you can see the following values in the log.

```
function
hello
function
hello
```